# forEach() and current element of an array

Tags: foreach, three.js

First question on stackOverflow.

Hi everybody,

I created a slide show with Three.js.

There is a uniform called uCorners (Vec2) that allows me to animate the corners of each image.

When the page loads, the timeline (gsap) starts instantly for 4 out of 5 images.
Only 1 image is controllable by the Dat.gui.

I don't see how I can animate each image independently.

Here is my code.

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'
import ExperienceSketch from '../ExperienceSketch'
import * as dat from 'dat.gui';
import Frag from '../../shader/fragment.glsl'
import Vert from '../../shader/vertex.glsl'
import image1 from '../../assets/img/texture.jpg'
import image2 from '../../assets/img/image2.webp'
import image3 from '../../assets/img/logo-acier.webp'
import gsap from 'gsap'


export default class Sketch
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.experience = new ExperienceSketch()
        this.camera = this.experience.camera
        this.scene = this.experience.scene
        this.sizes = this.experience.sizes
        this.time = this.experience.time
        
        this.cloths = [
            { title: 'Print#1', src: image1},
            { title: 'Print#2', src: image2},
            { title: 'Print#3', src: image3},
            { title: 'Print#4', src: image2},
            { title: 'Print#5', src: image3}
        ] 
        this.description = document.querySelector('div.description')
        this.prevTag = document.querySelector('nav a.prev')
        this.nextTag = document.querySelector('nav a.next')
        this.current = 0
        this.currentRotationY = 0
        this.aimRotationY = 0
        this.arc = (Math.PI * 2 / this.cloths.length)
        this.loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
        this.gui = new dat.GUI()
    
        this.loadObject()
        this.navigation()
        this.setupSettings()

    }

    setupSettings()
    {
        this.settings = { progress: 0 }
        this.gui.add(this.settings, "progress", 0, 1, 0.001)
    }

    loadObject()
    {
            this.cloths.forEach((cloth, index) =>{
                cloth.uniforms = {
                    uTime: { value: 1 },
                    uProgress: { value: 0 },
                    uTexture: { value: this.loader.load(cloth.src)},
                    uTextureSize: { value: new THREE.Vector2(100, 100 )},
                    uCorners: { value: new THREE.Vector2( 0,0 )},
                    uResolution: { value: new THREE.Vector2( this.sizes.width, this.sizes.height)},
                    uQuadSize: { value: new THREE.Vector2( 400, 400)}
                }
                
                this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 400, 400, 100, 100 );
                this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                uniforms: cloth.uniforms,
                vertexShader: Vert,
                fragmentShader: Frag
                })

                this.tl = gsap.timeline()
                .to(this.material.uniforms.uCorners.value, {
                    x: 1
                })
                .to(this.material.uniforms.uCorners.value, {
                    y: 1
                })
                  
                this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );

                this.group = new THREE.Group()
                this.group.add(this.mesh)
                this.group.rotation.set(0, index * this.arc, 0)
                this.mesh.position.set(0, 0, -800)
                
                this.scene.add( this.group )

                })

    }

    navigation()
    {
     
        const next = ()=>{
            this.current += 1
            this.aimRotationY += this.arc
            if(this.current > this.cloths.length - 1){
                this.current = 0
            }
            update()
        }

        const prev = ()=>{
            this.current -= 1
            this.aimRotationY -= this.arc
            if(this.current < 0){
                this.current = this.cloths.length - 1
            }
            update()
        }

        const update = ()=>{
            this.description.innerHTML = this.cloths[this.current].title 
        }
        update()

        this.prevTag.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
            event.preventDefault()
            prev()
        })

        this.nextTag.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
            event.preventDefault()
            next()
        })
    }

    update()
    {
        const diffy = (this.aimRotationY - this.currentRotationY) * 0.025
        this.currentRotationY += diffy
        this.camera.instance.rotation.set(0, this.currentRotationY, 0)   
        this.tl.progress(this.settings.progress)
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not very clear. You mention animation, but you do not show any code where you animate anything. If you mean switching through the images, the `forEach` (and any loop, really) will do that very quickly, and you are not rendering each change. Please describe exactly how you would like it to work, and how it's working (or not working) presently.

Comment: @TheJim01 I have modified my post, hoping that it will be more understandable